# Update delete add list of child entities through parent

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Is there a better way to `add, update, delete` child entities (**LIST**) based on the newly passed list of children?

**My updated function**

```
Parent parent = findById(id);

//make changes to parent attributes
//parent.setXyz(dto.getXyz());

//convert newly passed sons to hashmap
Map<String, Son> newSons = toHashMap(dto.getSons());

List<Son> finalSons = new ArrayList<>();

for (Son oldSon : parent.getSons()) {
    if (newSons.containsKey(oldSon.getUniqueString())) {
        finalSons.add(oldSon);
        newSons.remove(oldSon.getUniqueString());
    } else {
        //Delete the son thats not in new list
        sonRepository.delete(oldSon);
    }
}

//add remaining sons
for (Son son : newSons) {
    finalSons.add(son);
}

//existing.getSons().clear();
//existing.getSons().addAll(finalSons);
existing.getSons().clear();

parentRepository.save(parent);
```

**Parent entity**

```
@Entity(name = "parents")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Son> sons;
}
```

**Child entity**

```
@Entity(name = "sons")
public class Son {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Comment: It heavily depends on the mappings in `Parent` - when you make use of `CascadeType` and `orphanRemoval` you don't have to add/save/delete any children at all, you can simply make sure that the objects are set-up correctly and then save the parent and Hibernate will do the rest (save existing children if changed, add new children, remove the newly orphaned children). That said, please add the code for `Parent` and `Son` otherwise this is just speculation.

Comment: @Smutje updated question with entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your life a bit easier regarding to the updating process when you make use of JPA's `orphanRemoval` feature, but beware because it can result in you deleting stuff involuntarily:

## Parent.java

```
@Entity(name = "parents")
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Son> sons;
}
```

## Service

```
Parent parent = findById(id);

Map<String, Son> addedSons = toHashMap(dto.getSons());

// Remove existing sons that are not part of the update
parent.getSons().removeIf(existingSon -> !addedSons.containsKey(existingSon.getUniqueString()));

// Add new sons
addedSons.forEach(parent.getSons()::add);

// Save parent and trigger creating of added sons/deletion of removed existing sons
parentRepository.save(parent);
```